# Why is my RewriteRule not being interpretted as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a web page that uses a GET variable to select which page to display, for example, domain.com/index.php?page=contact

I want the URL to display as domain.com/services/contact

So I have written the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^services/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1   [NC,L]
```

However, if I visit domain.com/services, my PHP script is treating this as if I had visited domain.com/index.php?page=services

What is causing this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: And if you add leading slash: `/index.php?page=$1`?

Comment: That `RewriteRule` shouldn't even match 'domain.com/services'

Comment: @DusanBajic No change

Comment: Is that the only RewriteRule, or there are more?

Comment: @MarkusLaire Why not?

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes it is the only rule

Comment: Because that rule must have `services/` **plus at least one character after it**, so just 'domain.com/services' or 'domain.com/services/' will not match.

Comment: Is this RewriteRule in `.htaccess` file at your document root? Are you sure there **isn't** another file at `services/.htaccess` ?

Comment: This behavior cannot be duplicated as your rule won't rewrite `domain.com/services/`